# Custom tokenizer in tm package R not working

Tags: r, text, tm, mining

please see MWE below, the custom defined tokenizer is not working, why? tm package version is 0.71

```
library(tm)

ts <- c("This is a testimonial")
corpDs <- Corpus(VectorSource(ts))

#This is not working
ownTokenizer <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), "i+"))
tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpDs,control=list(tokenize=ownTokenizer))
as.matrix(tdm)

#This is working
ownTokenizer(ts)
```

Output:

> Terms
>
> Docs testimonial this
>
> 1           1    1
>
> [1] "Th"       "s "       "s a test" "mon"      "al"

Thank you,

Tobias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is somewhat stale now, but maybe it still helps others: You have to replace 
    corpDS<-Corpus(...)
by
    corpDS<-VCorpus(...)
As tm documentation states in the TermDocumentMatrix description, "SimpleCorpus" corpora are always tokenized with a fixed tokenizer - no costumization - it seems to be the same for "Corpus"...